# Whether there exists infimum of a union of all bounded subsets of $R$ which is closed under multiplication.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

The question is whether there exits $\inf(A)$ such that $A$ is the union of all bounded subset of $R$ where each subset is closed under multiplication.

I think the infimum exists because completeness axiom states every non-empty bounded subset of $R$ has supremum and thus infimum. So I am trying to show that $A$ is also bounded and subset of $R$. Yet, I can not figure out how to show it's bounded.

Is my conclusion that $\inf(A)$ exists correct?

Comment: Hint: Find all bounded sets of $\Bbb R$ that are closed under multiplication. If $x$ is in one of those sets, so is $x^n$ for every $n$.

Comment: Another hint: if a subset is closed under multiplication and contains an $a$ with $|a|>1$ it can not be bounded because all $a^n$ belong to it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Your hint implies that the absolute values of all elements of A must be equal or less than 1. Thus A is bounded and infimum exists by completeness. Right?

Comment: It is not hard to prove that $A=[-1,1]$ and the infimum, which is also the minimum, is $-1$.